# MVC 4 mobile with Jquery.mobile 1.4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, nuget, visual-studio-2013

I use VS 2013 with MVC 4 mobile. By default, it use Jquery.mobile 1.2 and JQuery 1.8.2. but I want to use Jquery.mobile 1.4 and Jquery 1.9.1

How can I config it????

Answer (score 1):

Open up Package Manager Console in VS 2013, type the following two commands to update the packages from NuGet...

```
PM> Install-Package jQuery -Version 1.9.1
PM> Install-Package jquery.mobile -Version 1.4.0
```